# Log admin activity to lan pc

Tags: windows

In a Windows 2k3 domain, all users use winXP, there is user X and user Y both administrators to the domain. 
User X (possible bad guy) can log in to Y’s pc and view files. 
Is there a way that user Y can log this activity ?
The point is that logging the activity is required and not just forbid using a firewall.

Thank you in advance 
And forgive me for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up Local Policy on Y’s computer to audit account logon events (Local Security Policy/Local Policies/Audit Policy).

Also, you can set auditing for each file you want – go to specific file’s properties, then in Security tab you can find Advanced button.

Click on Advanced button and go to Auditing tab. You can set auditing on file level there for specific user, in this case for your X user. I hope this helps.

For more details you can check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556015